# My problem is flutter Could not build the application for the simulator

Tags: ios

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           14.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp-bjmhehltlbmsykbtiuwslzejmjnf
    /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:493:38: error: no known class method for selector 'credentialWithProviderID:IDToken:rawNonce:accessToken:'
          credential = [FIROAuthProvider credentialWithProviderID:provider
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:502:38: error: no known class method for selector 'credentialWithProviderID:IDToken:rawNonce:'
          credential = [FIROAuthProvider credentialWithProviderID:provider
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 errors generated.
    /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTCloudFirestorePlugin.m:155:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereField:arrayContainsAny:'
            query = [query queryWhereField:fieldName arrayContainsAny:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTCloudFirestorePlugin.m:157:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereFieldPath:arrayContainsAny:'
            query = [query queryWhereFieldPath:fieldPath arrayContainsAny:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTCloudFirestorePlugin.m:163:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereField:in:'
            query = [query queryWhereField:fieldName in:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTCloudFirestorePlugin.m:165:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereFieldPath:in:'
            query = [query queryWhereFieldPath:fieldPath in:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    4 errors generated.
    gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp-bjmhehltlbmsykbtiuwslzejmjnf
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: You need to explain better the problem and not just copy/paste the error, man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't understand the problem I ended up here while looking for a similar problem. Here is how I solved it, in case anybody else bumps here with this kind of problem.

1 - updated Xcode.

2 - updated the plugins to the latest version from `pub.dev/flutter` (keep notes of the versions you are using because some plugins gave me problems so I kept the old version).

3 - upgraded flutter to the latest version: `flutter upgrade`

4 - inside the app `/ios` directory I ran: `pod update`

5 - on the app directory: `flutter clean` then `flutter run`

After all that, the problem was solved.